# Angular multiselect is not getting displayed properly

Tags: angular7

I am using Angular-multiselect of version 4.2.2. On UI it is coming like this.[image]

When I deselect Items and add once again then it is coming properly.

[image]

My HTML code

```
<div class="form-group mb-2">
                <label class="label-style"><b>Specializations:</b> </label>
                <angular2-multiselect [data]="specializations" [(ngModel)]="selectedSkills" [settings]="sOptions"
                  name="skills">
                </angular2-multiselect>
              </div>
```

My TS file

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sOptions = {
      singleSelection: false,
      text: "Select specializations",
      selectAllText: 'Select All',
      unSelectAllText: 'DeSelect All',
      enableSearchFilter: true,
      classes: "myclass custom-class ml-md-3 input-length",
      maxHeight: 100
    };}
```

Pls help me in fixing this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using angular +7 , try angular material or nebular ( i used them and they work perfectly )

if you decided to use those materials , nb-select tag or mat-select , have multiple attribute , and make sure you use placeholder attribute

for nebular theme , template going to be like this :

```
<nb-select formControlName="formControl"><nb-option [value]="value">label</nb-option></nb-select>
```

Comment: I'm not sure about binding options inside .ts file , I did not use options this way